# ASP.NET says FUNCTION does not exist when calling stored procedure

Tags: mysql, asp.net, stored-procedures

ADO.NET is being used to access a MySQL database in my application.  Some stored procedures were developed out of house.  I applied them to the database.  When trying to access a stored procedure in the database, the following exception occurs:

**FUNCTION your_db.log_insertLogMessage does not exist**

When calling this code:

```
MySqlCommand cmd = CreateCommand(procName, prams);
return cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

The procName is string which is set correctly.  Prams is MySqlParameter array.  In the debugger, "?" appears for the array values, when expanding in Visual Studio.

The database seems to be accessed with no issue.  I changed the database name to a dummy name and got a different error regarding the database not existing.

I removed all the stored procedures and received a new error saying a function or stored procedure with the given name did not exist.

I then reapplied the stored procedures, and I am now back to original error.  The code for the stored procedure is:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `log_insertLogMessage`<br>
(IN `Name` varchar(100), IN `Description` varchar(5000), IN `Message` varchar(5000)
)

begin

INSERT INTO DBlog(UserName, Descr, LogMessage, WhenOccurred) values(Name, Description, Message, CURDATE());

end
```

I am able to call the stored procedure without issue in MySQL itself.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

I figured out the problem.  I had to switch to an older verson mySql.data.dll.  The database was set up correctly, and the code was fine.  It was just a connector issue.